Kafka compatibilty with akka version 2.7.0
I have recently upgraded my jdk version from 8 to 17.
Akka 2.7.0
But I am getting following error
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS
at kafka.server.Defaults$.(KafkaConfig.scala:210)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.(KafkaConfig.scala:686)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:897)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:899)
at com.github.charithe.kafka.EphemeralKafkaBroker.buildKafkaConfig(EphemeralKafkaBroker.java:233)
at com.github.charithe.kafka.EphemeralKafkaBroker.startBroker(EphemeralKafkaBroker.java:144)
at com.github.charithe.kafka.EphemeralKafkaBroker.start(EphemeralKafkaBroker.java:124)


Older version->
compile group: "com.typesafe.akka", name: "akka-stream-kafka_2.12", version: "0.18"
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '1.0.0'
compile group: 'com.github.charithe', name: 'kafka-junit', version: '4.0.0'


New->
implementation group: "com.typesafe.akka", name: "akka-stream-kafka_2.12", version: "4.0.2"
implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '3.7.1'
implementation group: 'com.github.charithe', name: 'kafka-junit', version: '4.1.0'

Can someone help me with compatible versions of kafka with akka 2.7 ?

You may try with kafka-clients 3.6.2. There is also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/home.html

Thanks for reply. I tried but getting same error.
